# Disable and enable next input field that is inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How I can enable and disable the next input inside one div after check or uncheck a checkbox?
I'm trying with jQuery **nextAll**, but this don't work if a div is involving the elements. My HTML:

```
<input class='box' type='checkbox'/>Option - 
<div class='box-2' style='display: inline-block'>
    Quantity <input type='number' disabled/>
</div>
<input class='box' type='checkbox'/>Option 2 - 
<div class='box-2' style='display: inline-block'>
    Quantity <input type='number' disabled/>
</div>
```

I'm actually trying with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.box').change(function()
    {
        var set =  $(this).is(':checked') ? false : true;
        $(this).nextAll('div.box-2 input').first().attr('disabled', set);
    });
});
```

I know something's wrong, but I can't make it work.
[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvf7znxm/3/)

Comment: Try `.prop('disabled', true);` on the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function to find next element after checkbox (div in your case) and after that [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) input inside this div.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.box').click(function()
    {
        var set =  $(this).is(':checked') ? false : true;
        $(this).next('div.box-2').find('input').attr('disabled', set)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='box' type='checkbox'/>Option - 
<div class='box-2' style='display: inline-block'>
    Quantity <input type='number' disabled/>
</div>
<input class='box' type='checkbox'/>Option 2 - 
<div class='box-2' style='display: inline-block'>
    Quantity <input type='number' disabled/>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked great now. Thank you for the solution and for the explanation.

Comment: I have noticed now that if I use label element it don't work: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvf7znxm/5/
See the Option 2 input, please.

Comment: @Hypister right, because now `next()` function refers to `<label>Option 2 -</label>` (but you need to box-2). This will only works if you delete this label tag.

Comment: But I need the label tag. Is there a way to do this with the label tag?

Comment: @Hypister Sure! Just use `next()` function two times. Check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvf7znxm/7/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `next('.box-2')` and after that find `input`.

HTML:

```
<input class='box' type='checkbox'/>Option - 
<div class='box-2' style='display: inline-block'>
    Quantity <input type='number' disabled/>
</div>
<input class='box' type='checkbox'/>Option 2 - 
<div class='box-2' style='display: inline-block'>
    Quantity <input type='number' disabled/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').change(function(){
        var el = $(this).next('.box-2').find('input');
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            el.prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else{
            el.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvf7znxm/4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this also disables the checkbox.

Comment: @showdev The problem is that the input field inside box-2 div is not disabled or enabled when I check/uncheck the box checkbox close to it.

Comment: @MohammadReza Thank you, now worked, but I already accepted semanser's answer as the solution.

Comment: @Hypister Ok it's fine. you can vote this answer up :)

Comment: @MohammadReza Done.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, u should use .next().
.next() will fetch the next element and you can perform any operation on that element.

```
$('.box').click(function()
{
    var set =  $(this).is(':checked') ? false : true;
    $(this).next('div.box-2').find('input').attr('disabled', set)
});
```